# How to connect Bluetooth printer using Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, printing, bluetooth

Currently I am working on a project where I need to develop money collector module.

In that project money collector(Person) goes to customer and accept the money, for that he has to give a receipt using a thermal printer that money has been collected.

I am developing project for Windows Phone 7, I have a Bluetooth enabled printer and Window Phone 7 has also a Bluetooth but I don't know how to do programming for that.

Even Bluetooth company has not provided any SDK for Windows Phone 7. I am using Zebra MZ320 Printer.

Can anyone help me? or I have to develop that application on Windows Mobile 6?

Comment: This looks like "Please, can you do my work for me?" - Please look at the [FAQ#questions] about how to ask questions and also at the[FAQ#dontask] about what and how not to ask. Then maybe consider changing your question to a specific probelm you have encountered while trying to do the work yourself. If you show effort, and your question is reasonably scoped, there may be more people willing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently windows phone 7 bluetooth is only supports for handsfree and car audio kit.

Might be they will supports in windows phone 8 but not sure so it's better to go for Windows Mobile 6 or 6.5.

This link has more detail.

http://www.publisharticle.in/KB/8B2DC4A3F3114/Bluetooth-issue-in-windows-Phone-7

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

This isn't currently supported under windows phone 7 - the Bluetooth support is limited to just the audio profile.

This functionality might be available in windows phone 8 - more news available on this in the next month (probably)